# Values as labels in Box plots

Tags: sas, boxplot

I have the following sample of data

```
Y     X1      X2      X3    X4     ...
123  121     214     241   241
431  143     141     241   124
214  124     214     142   241
531  432     134     412   124
243  124     134     134   123
```

I would be interested in plotting using box plots the data above. Specifically, I would like to have on the x-axis X1, X2, ... and on the y-axis the information of values within each column as a box plot.
However, since I would like to identify visually, the corresponding Y'value (e.g., for max X1 would be 531), I thought about using some labels.
For creating the box plot, I am using

```
ods graphics off;
proc boxplot data=test;
   plot Y*X;
run;
```

where X is

```
X    Y
X1  121
X1  143
X1  124
X1  432
... ...
X2  214
X2  141
X2  214
...
```

As shown above, however, I am loosing the values of Y (i.e. 123, 431, ...).
Is there any way to keep also this information in a (box) plot? Any other ideas would be also kept into consideration and appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transpose your data and you will be able to use `Proc SGPLOT` statement `HBOX`.

Example:

```
data have;
input 
Y     X1      X2      X3    X4 ;
datalines;
123  121     214     241   241
431  143     141     241   124
214  124     214     142   241
531  432     134     412   124
243  124     134     134   123
;

proc transpose data=have out=tall (rename=col1=x);
  by y notsorted;
  var x1-x4;
run;

ods html file='hbox-plot.html';

proc sgplot data=tall;
   hbox x / category=y;
   yaxis type=linear;
run;

ods html close;
```

will produce

[image]

Comment: Thank you Richard. I was thinking that maybe also to use a secondary axis may fix the problem. What do you think? Is it something doable in SAS?

Comment: SAS graph producing procedures often provide for a second axis.  You also have the ability to programmatically annotate a graph or plot.